# Pre-Wiles' results on Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

IIRC, there was such a result as "there is no more than 1 non-trivial solution of $x^n+y^n=z^n$, if any", wasn't it? (IIRC, Siegel theorem implies that there are finitely many solutions for $n>3$; so it is the "no more than 1" part that is of particular interest).

Also, any reviews of pre-Wiles' results on Fermat's Last Theorem are appreciated.

Comment: Would that be up to common factors?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes.

Comment: Faltings' Theorem implies that for $n>3$, there are at most finitely many solutions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes... modulo IIRC, sorry. Precisely formulated result is the expected answer to my question.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell What about "there are at most 1 solution"? Yes, I may incorrectly remember... but it seems to me, that I had read such a result. That result was specific to Fermat's Last Theorem, and not to any homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: The only "at most one solution" result I can imagine in this context is that for given $x,y,z$ there is at most one $n$ such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$ (excluding trivialities like $x=1,y=-1,z=0$).

Answer (score 4):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) gives a good summary of pre-Wiles work. One highlight: In 1985, Leonard Adleman, Roger Heath-Brown and Étienne Fouvry proved that the first case of Fermat's Last Theorem holds for infinitely many odd primes $p$.